# Entityframework - Adding Expression to where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicate

Let's say I have this method to seach my DB for products that fit a certain keyword:

```
public List<Product> GetByKeyword(string keyword)
{
    using(var db = new DataEntities())
    {
        var query = db.Products.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(keyword);
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but somewhere else in my project, I want to get the **active products only**, still by keyword. I would like to do something like :

```
...
var result = ProductStore.GetByKeyword("Apple", x => x.isActive == 1);
```

Therefore, I created this method:

```
public List<Product> GetByKeyword(string keyword, Func<Product, bool> predicate = null)
{
    using(var db = new DataEntities())
    {
        var query = db.Products.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(keyword);
        if(predicate != null)
            query = query.Where(x => predicate(x));

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

While this compiles well, the ToList() call generates a **NotSupportedException** because LINQ does not support the Invoke method.

Of course, I could to it with another method 
i.e. *GetActiveByKeyword(string keyword)* but then I would have to do one for every possible variation, including the ones I didn't think of...

How do I get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just this:

```
if(predicate != null)
            query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: It does not compile like this, but it works if I change the parameter to be **Expression<Func<Product, bool>>**. I tried that before, I don't know why it works now...

Answer (score 0):

it's just as AD.Net says the reason why it works with `Expression` before is because if you say that the compiler knows it would be a lambda expression

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the intent is for the ORM of your choice to build a query, and when you call the `ToList()` function to fetch the records (materialize them), then using `Expressions<Func<Product,bool>>` will give you the best performance as it will form the query and let you continue building other expressions. In contrast, `Func<Product,bool>` is used after fetching the records into memory.

You can implement this like so.

```cs
public List<Product> GetByKeyword(string keyword, params Expression<Func<Product, bool>>[] predicate)
        {
            using(var db = new DataEntities())
            {
                var query = db.Products.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(keyword));

                foreach (var func in predicate)
                {
                    query = query.Where(func);
                }

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

You can then use it like this:

```cs
List<Product> result = GetByKeyword("Apple", x => x.isActive == 1, x => x.Description.Contains("Apple"));
```

Let me know if this helps.

Best regards.

Comment: The accepted answer is technically wrong.